# Query only doing half of what I want

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a function that is supposed to delete a product and, with it, delete its stock as well. But it keeps just deleting the stock. SSometimes I change the order of the querys and it shows an error that I can't delete idproduto because its an FK, so I put the delete stock query first. It deletes the stock and there's no error, but it doesn't delete the product.

Database:

TABLE produtos(idproduto, descr)
TABLE stock(idstock, idproduto, stock)

Code:

```
function removeProduto($idproduto){

        global $conn;
        $res="";
        $sql = "DELETE FROM stock WHERE idproduto= ".$idproduto.";";
    
        if($conn -> query($sql) === TRUE){

          $sql = "DELETE FROM produtos WHERE idproduto= ".$idproduto.";";
          
          $res = "Produto removido com sucesso";
    
        } else {

          $res = "Erro: ".$conn->error;
        }
    
        return($res);
    
    
    
    }
```

I also tried to put the delete produtos query right under the other, I switched them....

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [you may be at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Learn about [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4712113/5827005).

Comment: You don't do anything with `$sql` after changing it to `DELETE FROM produtos ...`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton thank you, i'm going to change it!

Comment: @JeffUK i do, i ust didn't show it with the code because it wasn't relevant, the error would be in the part of code i showed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use left join

```
DELETE s,p FROM stock s
   LEFT JOIN produtos p ON s.idproduto = p.idproduto
      WHERE idproduto = idproduto
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! At the beginning I had an error saying idproduto was ambiguous, because the program didn't know what idproduto to pick up, but i changed one of them and it works nicely, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: I have another question. I need to make an update on "descr" from produtos. The stock table also has that value as "description". The query should update the description in both the produtos table and the stock one. This is what I have "$sql = "UPDATE t FROM stock t LEFT JOIN produtos t2 ON t2.idproduto = t.idprod SET t.stock = '".$descricao."' WHERE idproduto = idprod;";". I took it off some different versios in stack overflow but none quite works.

Comment: This should work, you need to correct your column names `$sql = "UPDATE stock LEFT JOIN produtos ON produtos.idproduto = stock.idprod 
SET stock.column = '".$descricao."', produtos.column = ".$descricao.", WHERE stock.idproduto = idprod;";"` you beter use prepared statements you will be wide open to sql injections.

Comment: worked like a charm! yes, i'm going to try and pass it onto prepared statements later, i just need to have the basics working first :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a cascading foreign key constraint instead:

```
alter table stock add constraint fk_stock_product
    foreign key (idproduto) references produtos (idproduto)
    on delete cascade;
```

Then when a row is deleted from `produtos`, all stock is automatically deleted.

Comment: All stock? Like, the whole table? Or just the stock refering to that product?

Comment: The cascading delete removes all references to a product that has been deleted in the table where the foreign key is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming `$conn` is a `PDO` object... `PDO::query()` returns a `PDOStatement` and not a boolean. Comparing if the object is equal to `true` will always be `false`.